# How to modifiy a file in real time using shiny?

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny

I want to create a shiny app that do two things. Frist it has to be able to upload XLS file and after the user can add it some columns (in this case, just the column "Tecnico"), but for the moment I cant be able to do that. Once the user write the value for the column and update the table, the app crashed.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Use readxl"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                    accept = c(".xlsx")),textInput("tecnix","Tecnico"),
        actionButton("go", "update")),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('my_output_data'))
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){
      
      data1 <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}
       
        isolate({ 
          input$file1
          my_data <- read_excel(inFile$datapath)
        })
        my_data
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$go, {
         data1()$Técnico <- input$tecnix
        })
      
      output$my_output_data <- renderTable({data1()})  
      
    }
))
```

Any ideas?

Thank you so much,

Comment: Look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747121/r-shiny-cant-change-reactive-dataframe-object). You should use `reactiveVal()` or `reactiveValue()` instead of `reactive()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Till using `reactiveValues` will help solve the problem.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Use readxl"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                    accept = c(".xlsx")),textInput("tecnix","Tecnico"),
          actionButton("go", "update")),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('my_output_data'))
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){
      rv <- reactiveValues(my_data = NULL)
      
      observeEvent(input$file1, {
        req(input$file1$datapath)
        rv$my_data <- read_excel(input$file1$datapath)
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$go, {
        rv$my_data$Techni <- input$tecnix
      })
      output$my_output_data <- renderTable({rv$my_data})  
    }
  ))
```